# ggplot delete specific x-axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2017-12-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-02-01", 
                                  "2018-03-01", "2018-04-01", "2018-05-01", 
                                  "2018-06-01", "2018-07-01", "2018-08-01", 
                                  "2018-09-01", "2018-10-01", "2018-11-01")), 
                 value = c(0.567859562, 0.514907158, 0.035399304, 0.485728823, 
                           0.925127361, 0.237531067, 0.301930968, 0.133373326, 
                           0.082275426, 0.464255614, 0.2366749, 0.652084264))

ggplot(df, aes(date, value)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", 
                 date_labels = "%b") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.3))
```

I want to maintain my plot shown below, exactly as is, with two exceptions. I want to remove the first `Nov` on the x-axis label and the last `Dec` on the x-axis label. I added `coord_cartesian(xlim = as.Date(c("2017-12-01", "2018-11-01")))` to my code chunk above, but this eliminates the 'blank space' padding at either end of my x-axis.

How do I simply tell ggplot to delete the text of the first and last x-axis labels? This would be the first `Nov` and the last `Dec`. *Note* that these do not exists in my `df` data frame at all so `dplyr` filters probably won't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. The `date_breaks` are unnecessary.

```
ggplot(df, aes(date, value)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b", breaks = df$date) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.3))
```

[image: Resulting plot]

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve what you want by setting breaks using seq.date:

```
library(tidyverse);library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2017-12-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-02-01", 
                                  "2018-03-01", "2018-04-01", "2018-05-01", 
                                  "2018-06-01", "2018-07-01", "2018-08-01", 
                                  "2018-09-01", "2018-10-01", "2018-11-01")), 
                 value = c(0.567859562, 0.514907158, 0.035399304, 0.485728823, 
                           0.925127361, 0.237531067, 0.301930968, 0.133373326, 
                           0.082275426, 0.464255614, 0.2366749, 0.652084264))



ggplot(df, aes(date, value)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_x_date(
               date_labels = "%b",
               breaks = seq.Date(ymd("2017-12-01"),ymd("2018-11-01"), by = "month")) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.3))
```

[image]

Comment: Is the sequence necessary in this instance? I can see that it is a useful and more flexible tool for selecting labels, so good to know, but my understanding is that the questioner simply wants to the display the dates that are in their df, rather than the bookend dates added by date_breaks - so they can simply refer to those instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest researching the Lubridate package in R - you would be able to convert any messy date values into approrpiate POSIXT format and can also extract month information really easily - you could also convert those dates into a single column of the actual months, and use that as your axis label, which is cleaner as you would have an additional column of just the corresponding month - you can also fill based on that month and do some other cool stuff!